# Fetching of email subject is not working properly by using Gmail APIs in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail-api

I am creating a user in my Application and  trying to click on the activation link from the Gmail for that user. For that i am using Gmail APIs. When i am running the full code, i am creating 3 users and and i am able to click on activation link for first 2 users and able to login with new credentials. But when trying to click on the activation link for 3rd user, it says 'no email found'. My code is given below.

```
     public class GMail {
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Cloudium";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String USER_ID = "me";
/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH =  
        System.getProperty("user.dir") +
         File.separator + "src" +
         File.separator + "test" +
         File.separator + "java" +
         File.separator + "com" +
         File.separator + "dataSources" +
         File.separator + "client_secret.json";

private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
        File.separator + "src" +
        File.separator + "test" +
        File.separator + "java" +
        File.separator + "com" +
        File.separator + "dataSources";
/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
 * @return An authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
 */
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH));
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
     }
           GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new 
 InputStreamReader(in));
           // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9999).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}


public static Gmail getService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    return service;
}
public static List<Message> listMessagesMatchingQuery(Gmail service, String userId,
                                                      String query) throws IOException {
    ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query).execute();
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    while (response.getMessages() != null) {
        messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
        if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
            String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
            response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query)
                    .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return messages;
}
public static Message getMessage(Gmail service, String userId, List<Message> messages, int index)
        throws IOException {
    Message message = service.users().messages().get(userId, messages.get(index).getId()).execute();
    return message;
}
public static HashMap<String, String> getGmailData(String query) {
    try {
        Gmail service = getService();
        List<Message> messages = listMessagesMatchingQuery(service, USER_ID, query);
        Message message = getMessage(service, USER_ID, messages, 0);
        JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(message.toString());
        String subject = jp.getString("payload.headers.find { it.name == 'Subject' }.value");
        String body = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(jp.getString("payload.parts[0].body.data")));
        String link = null;
        String arr[] = body.split("\n");
        for(String s: arr) {
            s = s.trim();
            if(s.startsWith("<http") || s.startsWith("<https")) {
                link = s.trim();
                link = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("subject", subject);
        hm.put("body", body);
        hm.put("link", link);
        return hm;
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("email not found....");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static int getTotalCountOfMails() {
    int size;
    try {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        List<Thread> threads = service.
                users().
                threads().
                list("me").
                execute().
                getThreads();
         size = threads.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception log " + e);
        size = -1;
    }
    return size;
}

public static boolean isMailExist(String messageTitle) {
    try {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        ListMessagesResponse response = service.
                users().
                messages().
                list("me").
                setQ("subject:" + messageTitle).
                execute();
        List<Message> messages = getMessages(response);
        return messages.size() != 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception log" + e);
        return false;
    }
}
    
    private static List<Message> getMessages(ListMessagesResponse response) {
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        try {
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
            while (response.getMessages() != null) {
                messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
                if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                    String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                    response = service.users().messages().list(USER_ID)
                            .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return messages;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception log " + e);
            return messages;
        }
    }

}
```

and i am calling this in

```
   @Test
   public void readGamil() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);     
    HashMap<String, String> hm = GMail.getGmailData("subject:Fairjob Registration");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println(hm.get("link"));
    navigateTo(hm.get("link"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
}
```

Same email is generating with different username for activating the users and it should take the latest email if they having same subject. Can anyone help me on why it is not working for 3rd user? Thanks in advance.